# Azure setting recursive ACL results in 403 - updating goes okay though

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm using the Az.Storage cmdlets in Powershell to set the permissions on an Azure Data Lake gen 2 storage account. I have "owner" permissions, along with "Data Storage Owner" via my Azure AD account.

I can run the cmdlet "Update-AzDataLakeGen2AclRecursive" without issue, but if i instead try to 'replace' the permissions, using "set-AzDataLakeGen2AclRecursive", i get the following error:

```
Set-AzDataLakeGen2AclRecursive : An error occurred while recursively changing the access control list. See the InnerException of type Azure.RequestFailedException with Status=403 
and ErrorCode=SetAclMissingAces for more information.  You can resume changing the access control list using ContinuationToken= after addressing the error.
At file.ps1:62 char:9
+         Set-AzDataLakeGen2AclRecursive -Context $context -FileSystem  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzDataLakeGen2AclRecursive], DataLakeAclChangeFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DataLakeAclChangeFailedException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.SetAzDataLakeGen2AclRecursiveCommand
```

I'm not entirely sure why i'd get a 403 in this scenario, as it appears i have the correct permissions on the account already. (Having created the storage account with that same account - and reading the documentation, and finding that 'Data Storage Owner' was required)

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this one - you must make sure your AD Principal has permissions at the container level to be able to access it in the first place.

For me - this meant granting my AAD Account read/write/execute + default perms on the container that i was attempting to modify before using the "Set-" cmdlet.